# Converting Strings independent from decimal symbol

Tags: vba, casting, type-conversion

Following situation:

I am reciving a XML file with an XSD restriction:
`xs:decimal`

Now I want my code to sum up some of those decimals and do something with it.
Luckily I recognised that the CDbl function acts differently with different decimal symbol settings in windows, when given a string:

Windows settings decimal symbol: `.`

```
?cdbl("31.3") -> 31.3
?cdbl("31,3") -> 313
```

Windows settings decimal symbol: `,`

```
?cdbl("31.3") -> 313
?cdbl("31,3") -> 31,3
```

What is the proper way to handle this? Should I ask windows about the decimal symbol and `?replace()` it accordingly before using the CDbl function and summing up?

Comment: You can ask `Application` instead of Windows: `Debug.Print Application.DecimalSeparator, Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)`

Comment: That code doesn´t work with Access VBA.

So I will try this:

    Public Function getDecimalSeparatorOfSystem() As String
        getDecimalSeparatorOfSystem = Mid$(22 / 4, 2, 1)
    End Function

Hoped there was a better solution...